# How to update ms access table

Tags: c#, ms-access

How to update ms access table which contains single column with multiple rows. the table is showing on a `listview` and whenever I delete a row from `listview` then the row should be deleted from table. How can I do this. Using C#. I created a oledb connection and
I delete a row from list view checked item. That is the code:

```
if (listView1.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView1.CheckedItems)
       listView1.Items.Remove(lvi);
}
```

Now how can I update ms acesss table?

Comment: you dont need the if condition.. foreach is enumerated only if there is something inside the collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an OleDB command that performs an sql DELETE query for the row.

EDIT:
Does the table contain only one column? And that column is what you are displaying in the listview? Then you can do something like this:

```
using (OleDBCommand deleteCommand = connection.CreateCommand())
{
  deleteCommand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tablename WHERE colname=@rowvalue";
  deleteCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rowvalue", YourRowValue);
  deleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

This code snippet assumes that you have an open OleDBConnection named connection. Just replace tablename with the name of your table, colname with the name of the column, and YourRowValue with the value you want to delete and you should have something that works.

To delete all checked items you should encapsulate the code above in a method, say `DeleteItem(string name)` And use the following:

```
List<ListViewItem> itemsToBeDeleted = new List<ListViewItem>(listView1.CheckedItems); 
foreach (ListViewItem itemToDelete in itemsToBeDeleted)
{ 
   DeleteItem(itemToDelete.Text);
   listView1.Items.Remove(itemToDelete); 
}
```

Comment: thnax but when i delete a row from list view checked item then..... how to update